# Using Apple Configurator to install and *TRUST* an Enterprise App

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, software-distribution, trust, apple-configurator

I am able to install my Enterprise built iOS app through Apple Configurator 2.2.1 alongside my Enterprise Provisioning profile.

However, when I try to run the app it fails with the message that the developer cannot be trusted. I can manually look the profile up on the device's settings and Entrust it manually, my problem is I don't know how to automate this step by *AUTOMATICALLY ENTRUSTING* the Enterprise developer entity.

I understand I need to create something named a "Trust Profile" and apply it. My question is how to I create such a profile and how do I install it through the Apple Configurator.